# Komodo Edit "new command" options memory

Tags: komodo, komodoedit

I am using Komodo Edit 5.2.4. I have set up a custom "new command" which takes some input from the user and executes a program with it. This works fine, but I want the ability to default the options to the options the user previously selected the last time they ran the command.

I can't figure out how to do this, although I can see that previous entries are recorded in the combobox itself...any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [prompt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536673) to assign the options to a variable, then run the command using [runEncodedCommand](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/5.1/macroapi.html#macroapi_runencodedcommand)

```
komodo.assertMacroVersion(2);
if (komodo.view && komodo.view.scintilla) { komodo.view.scintilla.focus(); }

function runmemo()
  {
  if (!this.param)
    {
    this.param = window.prompt("What you really want");
    }
ko.run.runEncodedCommand("window", "echo {1: '"+escape(this.param)+"'}");
  }
runmemo();
```